# Is there a plugin that counts posts by author?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I want to have a page listing all the authors and the number of posts each of them has published. Is there a plugin that does this already? Being able to count number of comments as well would be a plus.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about a plugin but you can use this:

In author.php you can use this to count posts:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$curauth = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$post_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_author = '" . $curauth->ID . "' AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'");
?>
<h2>Post Count: <?php echo $post_count; ?></h2>
```

Inside a Loop you can use this to count posts and comments:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$user_id = $post->post_author;  //change this if not in a std post loop
$where = 'WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND user_id = ' . $user_id ;
$comment_count = $wpdb->get_var(
    "SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total
        FROM {$wpdb->comments}
        {$where}
    ");
$user = get_userdata($user_id);
$post_count = get_usernumposts($user->ID);
echo '<p>User ' . $user->display_name . ' post count is ' . $post_count .', comment count is ' . $comment_count . '</p>';
?>
```

For All Authors:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$where = 'WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND user_id <> 0';
$comment_counts = (array) $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT user_id, COUNT( * ) AS total
        FROM {$wpdb->comments}
        {$where}
        GROUP BY user_id
    ", object);
foreach ( $comment_counts as $count ) {
  $user = get_userdata($count->user_id);
  $post_count = get_usernumposts($user->ID);
  echo '<p>User ' . $user->display_name . ' post count is ' . $post_count .', comment count is ' . $count->total . '</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Philip. I tried your first and second snippets and I made author.php display number of posts and number of comments. However, I couldn't get the third snippet to work. I created a page template and put your code in it, but it didn't work. I guess it doesn't work in a page template. I actually installed "Member List" plug-in and I wanted to use your code to display # of posts and comments in the member list page, but I couldn't get it to work either. PHP looks like Latin to me. Anyway, thanks for the answer. I will wait a bit more, if nobody knows plugins, I will mark your answer.