# $user_login is not working if author has only 1 post

Tags: users, login

I display author login name and total posts count on profile page.

Everything works fine if author has 2 or more posts.

But if author has only 1 post, then login or user name not appear and post count displays all posts number in the website instead of showing 1.

What is missing?

```
<?php
                  global $wp_query;
                   $author_id = $wp_query->queried_object_id;
                   $user_id = $post->post_author;

                   $user = get_userdata($user_id);
                   $post_count = count_user_posts($user->ID);
                   echo '<p>Author: ' . $user->user_login . ' has published' . $post_count . 'posts ' .  '';
```

Comment: Could be the 1 post  is in a different post type not "post"?

Comment: No, it is same. I also tried with other authors.

Comment: If you could set a live link to the site with the issue I could take a look

Comment: Thank you for your help.

I found a solution. This post helped me: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13582/is-there-a-plugin-that-counts-posts-by-author/13590#13590